# is there a way to change jcheckbox to use a cross instead of a tick? JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I have a Jcheckbox but it only has the tick to show its checked, is there a way i can change it to a cross, or circle?
and is there a way to change the grey background to white the setBackground doesn't seem to make a difference?

Comment: is it possible to do with standard stuff as i dont want to add custom classes if i can help it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User setPressedIcon, setIcon and setDisabledIcon

```
    JCheckBox b = new JCheckBox();
    b.setPressedIcon(pressedIcon)
    b.setIcon(defaultIcon);
    b.setDisabledIcon(disabledIcon)
```

Comment: great but what is the pressedIcon, is it an icon i define myself or a standard one i can get from somewhere?