# Is it possible to have a checkbox that uses a slash and not a check mark?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a program that scores hit and misses. I would like to make it so that hits are checked and misses are left blank but in place of a check mark, can I use a slash so that the output would look something like below?

[image]

Comment: What UI toolkit are you using? Swing? SWT? AWT? JavaFX?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365069/is-there-a-way-to-change-jcheckbox-to-use-a-cross-instead-of-a-tick-java

Comment: If you're using Swing, then the answer @DavieBrown pointed you to is the best way.